# Can I create non-selfclosing tags via jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I create non-selfclosing tags via the following call in jQuery?

```
  let autorefreshLabel = $('<label/>', {
    text: 'Autorefresh after ' + autorefreshTimer + ' seconds...'
  });
```

Or is it possible to use this function for the self-closing tags like `input` only?

It works in Chrome, but I don't know whether it is guaranteed or not.

Comment: This feature is just a composition of other functions; doesn't depend on anything native. So if it works that way in one browser, it will work that way in any browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jquery will just create the ending tag itself when you create an element like that. Just type eg $('') in you developer tools on you website that supports jquery and you'll see.

you can always refer to the jquery docs on creating elements: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2